# Search through string and return true if match - working when only one value within string but not two?

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm trying to run a search against a string, which contains email domains. I have gotten it to work when there is only one word within the string but when I add in the second word it no longer workers. Any insight?

**Working**

```
trigger LeadFinder on Lead (before insert) {
    
    static Boolean keywordSearch(String input, String keywordPhrase)
        {
            return Pattern.compile('(?i)\\b' + keywordPhrase + '\\b').matcher(input).find();
        }
    
    String hchs = 'hotmail';
    
    for (Lead l : Trigger.new) {
        if(keywordSearch(l.Email, hchs) == true){      
        l.Description = 'found';
        }
    }
}
```

**Not Working**

```
trigger LeadFinder on Lead (before insert) {
    
    static Boolean keywordSearch(String input, String keywordPhrase)
        {
            return Pattern.compile('(?i)\\b' + keywordPhrase + '\\b').matcher(input).find();
        }
    
    String hchs = 'hotmail msn';
    
    for (Lead l : Trigger.new) {
        if(keywordSearch(l.Email, hchs) == true){      
        l.Description = 'found';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use regular expression syntax to insert "or" logic. For a two domain search like in your example, that would mean:

```
(?i)\b(hotmail|msn)\b
```

So you can just replace your spaces with single pipes here. You may need to add some logic to do string replacement depending on where you are getting these values from.

Comment: This works perfect, thank you Adrian!